# How to wrap SQL transaction in Go with existing repository that doesn't use sql.Tx?

Tags: sql, go, transactions, domain-driven-design

I have a service to create a lot of data in one go. Let's say I create `user -> user pic -> user contact -> user address`

Each table for it I create per domain. Say, in `user domain` I have a repository to create the user like this :

```golang
stmt, err := db.Prepare(query)
checkError(err)

err = stmt.QueryRowContext(ctx, ...data).Scan(...model)
checkError(err)

return model
```

Each repository in my case is using a `Create Statement` as shown above, and I don't use `db.BeginTx()`.

This is the one service I talk about:

```golang
dataUser, errCreate := user.repository.Create(ctx, modelUser)

dataPic, errCreatePic := pic.repository.Create(ctx, modelUserPic)

dataContact, errCreateContact := contact.repository.Create(ctx, modelUserContact)

dataAddress, errCreateAddress := address.repository.Create(ctx, modelUserAddress)
```

But if one call fails, in the middle, the parent is going to be committed here. Is it possible to **wrap** `Transaction` on that case in my existing repository I create?

Or should I create a Method in the repository to handle for instance `CreateWithTransaction()` ?

Comment: That depends on the type of DB. If it's *sql.DB you can't do anything. If it's an interface that's implemented by *sql.Tx just pass a transaction instead of the db.

Comment: if *sql.Tx , how can i make the ` tx.Commit() ` in the  service ? should i call interface of DB as well in service ?? @Peter

Comment: You can't (and wouldn't want to) do it in the service. That would defeat the purpose. The caller is responsible for committing the transaction.

Comment: did u mean I should manipulation and do re query insert statement in service ?? @Peter

Comment: Maybe you should design your program with "Domain" instead of "Database Schema". Since they are highly coupled, make them into a function: `CreateUser` **NOT** `CreateUser`, `CreateUserPic`, `CreateUserAddress`.. etc.

Answer (score 3):

Much depends on how your entire architecture is set up. There are many variations and considerations to take into account (I won't go into detail, as there's plenty of documentation out there). But in general a best-practice is if the domain model - and in many cases even the Services - is entirely independent of any implementation choices. It shouldn't be aware of SQL transactions.

For instance, if `User` is an Aggregate Root in DDD terminology and `Picture`, `Contact` and `Address` are Value Objects, then `User` is responsible for consistency.

In my own DDD code I use a [Ports and Adapters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_architecture_(software)) architecture and [CQRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation#Command_query_responsibility_segregation). I might have a `UpdateUserDetails` Command in the Application layer that is passed a Repository implementation (e.g. for a SQL database) and does the transaction handling. The Domain layer would just define the Repository interface.

The command handler retrieves the Aggregate Root object i.e. `User` from the repository and does the updating on that (again various ways to implement e.g. in a single `User.UpdateDetails()` or in multiple steps in the handler itself). Only after this is done without any validation or business rules errors, does the handler persist to the repository and here I wrap calls into a Transaction.

My code - being very specific - would not be useful for you, though.

Instead check the great [Wild Workouts](https://github.com/ThreeDotsLabs/wild-workouts-go-ddd-example) example for a complete intro of DDD for Go, and including transaction handling. The blog series gradually refactors an application, introducing ever more DDD-related concepts. It starts with a "DDD lite" version (best-practice: start as simple as possible), then adds CQRS and even goes to Event Sourcing and Microservices (where due to 'eventual conistency' transactions would be handled entirely differently).

Specifically the series' article [The Repository pattern: a painless way to simplify your Go service logic](https://threedots.tech/post/repository-pattern-in-go/), offers some insightful ideas on how to handle your transactions.

Answer (score 0):

instead of declaring a repository such as

```golang
type UserRepo struct{
   db *sql.DB
}
func (s UserRepo)Create(ctx context.Context, u modelUser) error{ ... }
```

Prefer a signature such as

```golang
type Execer interface {
    ExecContext(ctx context.Context, query string, args ...interface{}) (sql.Result, error)
}
type Querier interface {
    QueryContext(ctx context.Context, query string, args ...interface{}) (*sql.Rows, error)
}

type UserRepo struct{}
func (s UserRepo)Create(ctx context.Context, db Execer, u modelUser) error{ ... }
```

It adds two interfaces that abstract the concrete underlying type of the DB.

In consequence, within the caller you can write something similar to

```golang
    db := GetDB()
    tx := db.Begin()
    var err error
    defer func() {
        if err == nil {
            err = tx.Commit()
        } else {
            err = tx.Rollback() // or use a []error, or else, to not shadow the underlying error.
        }
    }()

    var dataUser something
    dataUser, err = user.repository.Create(ctx, tx, modelUser)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    var dataPic something
    dataPic, err = pic.repository.Create(ctx, tx, modelUserPic)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    // etc
```

When you need not to start a transaction, just pass in the db instance,

```golang
db:=GetDB()

dataUser, err := user.repository.Create(ctx, db, modelUser)
if err != nil {return err}

dataPic, err := pic.repository.Create(ctx, db, modelUserPic)
if err != nil {return err}
// etc
```

Consider that if you need retryable ops, you should wrap the whole code responsible to begin/end the transaction.

https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Tx

`After a call to Commit or Rollback, all operations on the transaction fail with ErrTxDone.`